# Python: How to load large audio data set quickly

Tags: python, audio, wav, m4a

I'm new to working with large amounts of data. I have a pretty big data set (around 1 million audio files each a couple seconds long), and I'm trying to load the data in an efficient manner for visualization purposes (and eventually to use as training data in a neural network).

What I've tried so far is using librosa (used librosa.load(filename)) but this took a couple hours just to load 10,000 of the files. I tried to find out if I could use a GPU to speed it up (fumbled around with Numba) but I'm not clear if this is even a valid problem for a GPU to solve.

I feel like I'm missing something really obvious. Can someone more experienced tell me what to do? I am having a hard time trying to find the solution on the Internet. Thanks for the help!

Comment: what is the audio format?

Comment: .m4a but I am having similar issues with loading .wav files as well

Comment: If files are of equal length, you can try merging them into larger batches using external software (e.g. using `sox` in command line), and loading batches to python, and splitting them again for processing. This might be faster than the python IO loop.

Comment: They aren't all the same length unfortunately

Comment: Can you share the code that demonstrates how you load the file? What is the sampling rate?

Comment: "for file in filenames: y, sr = librosa.load(filename)" is the code I'm using. The sampling rate is 16 kHz, and it takes around 0.3 seconds to load each file, but it takes the same to load the files even with a sampling rate of 100 Hz.

Answer (score 0):

You could use pygame.
In this mini program I made, I tested out how long I takes to load a sound file that is about 10 seconds long:

```
import pygame
import time

pygame.init()
time_now = time.time()
sound = pygame.mixer.music.load('music.wav')
print(time.time() - time_now)
```

And this is the result is:

```
0.0
```

And if you want to play that file, you do:

```
pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=int, start=float)
```

It will take about 1-4 hour(s) to load all of them still.
For further info, go to https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html .